# Holomorphicity of the ratio of zeta functions

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions, entire-functions, l-functions

It is known that for a soluble extension of algebraic number fields $L:K$, the ratio of the Dedekind $\zeta$-functions $\frac{\zeta_L(s)}{\zeta_K(s)}$ is an entire function.

It is also conjectured (Artin) that the above holds for any Galois extension $L:K$.

My question is whether or not there exists some corresponding conjecture that applies for all (not necessarily Galois) field extensions.

$\textit{E.g.}$ if we let $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, so that $L:K$ is not a normal extension, can anything be said about the holomorphicity of $\frac{\zeta_L(s)}{\zeta_K(s)}$, and is it even meaningful to consider these extensions? If so, how come I have never seen the case of non-Galois extensions addressed in the literature?

Comment: @user714237 Yes, I've got it wrong. I thought this was the state of affairs after reading Neukirch. I find it remarkable that he doesn't even mention the Aramata-Brauer theorem. The only reference I have found to this theorem is on p. 83 of $\textit{An introduction to the Langlands Program}$. Do you know any textbooks that deal with the Aramata-Brauer theorem?

Comment: @user714237 Thanks for the reference. I understand how the Artin conjecture would imply the Aramata-Brauer theorem as a corollary of inductive invariance, but how does the holomorphicity of the Artin L-functions imply the holomorphicity of the ratio of the zeta functions corresponding to $\textit{any}$ finite field extension $E/K$? This claim was also made on p. 83 of $\textit{An Introduction to the Langlands Programme}$, but no justification was provided.